# Most efficient way to split a string up by a delimiter while ignoring certain instances of said delimiter using excel vba

Tags: arrays, regex, vba, excel

I have a very redundant piece of old code, which I created when I first discovered and decided to learn vba (and man have I come a long way). I was using this code to cycle through cells that contained multiple values delimited with commas. However, there are cases where I can't simply use something such as the `Split(string,",")` function  because some of the values have commas within that value (example value:*[blah blah, so blah blah]*). In instances where these brackets exist (they are around every value that has a comma within it) I devised the rather long-winded approach that is my old method to properly split the values up, dump them in an array and then proceed with my other tasks. But, now I've decided to revisit the code and fix the accuracy. Here is some background.

**Sample Data that can be found in *one* cell:**
<sup>Please Note: This is data that suppliers send us, we don't have control over what they enter or how they enter it. This is a simple example to show the gist of how the data typically is provided in some cases</sup>

```
Available on 2 sides: Silkscreen,[full: color, covers entire face],Pad Print: One color,[heat transfer, may bleed]
```

Values are:

- Available on 2 sides: Silkscreen
- [full: color, covers entire face]
- Pad Print: One color
- [heat transfer, may bleed]

**What I'm looking for:**
I'm looking for a more efficient and simpler method to be able to split up values correctly (while keeping the brackets for the values that have them).

I believe I have managed to create a much more efficient and compact method to handle instances that don't include brackets using the following code

**New Code (Under Construction):**
I'm having issues with not knowing how to efficiently and accurately split the cells with brackets

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rngXid As Range, RegularColons As New Collection, UpchargeColons As New Collection, additionals As Range, upcharges As Range, Colon, UpchargeColon
    Dim Values() As String, endRange As Long, xidMap As Object, xid As String, NumberofValues As Integer
    endRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set xidMap = getXidMap(ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & UsedRange.Rows.Count)) 'Map products for quicker navigation
    Set additionals = ActiveSheet.Range("AJ:AK"): Set upcharges = ActiveSheet.Range("CS:CT")
    Set RegularColons = FindAllMatches(additionals, ":") 'This returns all instances/cells that contain a colon in the specified columns
    If Not RegularColons Is Nothing Then
        For Each Colon In RegularColons
            xid = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Colon.Row).Value
            If InStr(1, Colon.Value, "[") = 0 Then 'If no brackets then simply split
                Values = Split(Trim(Colon.Value), ",")
            Else
                'This is where I'm at a lose for a more effective method
                '-----------Populate Values array with Colon.Value while watching out for brackets--------
            End If
            Set rngXid = xidMap(xid).EntireRow.Columns(upcharges) 'set to this specific product
            For ColorLocation = LBound(Values) To UBound(Values) 'cycle through each value in Values array
                If Not InStr(1, Values(ColorLocation), ":") = 0 Then 'Only proceed if the value has a colon
                    Set UpchargeColons = FindAllMatches(rngXid, Values(ColorLocation)) 'Searching other columns for this value
                    If Not UpchargeColons Is Nothing Then
                        For Each UpchargeColon In UpchargeColons 'If found in other columns proceed to replace colon
                            UpchargeColon.Value = Replace(UpchargeColon.Value, ":", " ")
                            Log UpchargeColon.Range, "Removed Colon from Additional Color/Location Upcharge", "Corrected" 'This is a custom sub of mine to record the change
                        Next UpchargeColon
                    End If
                    Values(ColorLocation) = Replace(Values(ColorLocation), ":", " ")
                End If
            Next ColorLocation
            Log Colon.Range, "Removed Colon(s) from Additional Color/Location Value(s)", "Corrected"
        Next Colon
    End If
End Sub
```

I've been browsing possible ways to do this and the one that keeps sticking out is `Regex`, which admittedly I have absolutely no experience with although I have previously heard of it. So, I tried reading up on it a bit using sites like [this](https://blog.udemy.com/vba-regex/) and of course the [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). My observations/thoughts while trying to learn a little more about this method are:

1. This is absolutely, terrifyingly complex and overwhelming. So much so I have to refrain from crawling into a corner, assuming fetal position, and bawling my eyes out.
2. I can't seem to find anything that would suggest how I could incorporate this function with my need to split the string appropriately, at least as far as I can see. But, it may just be that I get so overwhelmed by all the seemingly random symbol sequences

**So, my question is:**
What would be the most efficient way to accurately split up the values in cells that contain brackets?

Comment: If this works as intended but is simply ugly, it would be better to post it on [codereview.se]

Comment: That said regex is indeed scary *at first*, but the dragon can be tamed =)

Comment: Good point, I'll learn eventually haha (sorry!). Could you possibly migrate it for me?

Comment: I've heard that from a few people that preach its use. Maybe one day, but I don't think I'm to that point yet

Comment: FWIW I've flagged it for migration to CR.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it (really). Also, I apologize again for not being able to correctly determine which site to post this on. I know you've been very tolerant of me.

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder actually the problem with regular expressions is not that they are very complicated, but rather that they are too simplistic, i.e., they are very "dumb" and can only parse the simplest of text effectively.

Comment: Well, your code works, right? I'd suggest you [edit] to include the full method though, to make a better CR post.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Well yes, but the entire code for this particular sub is 300+ lines and is very novice. My new code is basically complete and listed above. I just need help with the last bit of my **new** code (sorting out the problem with cells with brackets). Now I'm feeling like this belongs on here more than CR after explaining (sorry!).

Comment: I'd edit the post to clarify then - perhaps remove the old code completely, and ask your specific question about handling brackets.

Comment: Noted and will do that now thanks!

Comment: What happens if you're provided with values that contain square brackets within square brackets? Eg. Note the `[C,Y,M,K]` within `Available on 2 sides: Silkscreen,[full: color[C,M,Y,K], covers entire face],Pad Print: One color,[heat transfer, may bleed]`

Comment: That doesn't happen with the way our data is structured/how it exports.

Comment: Just FYI, the regex flavor used in VBA is the same as those found in JavaScript, VBScript, and other ECMAScript implementations.  It's *not* the same as the .NET flavor, which has a much richer feature set.  So if you want to learn regexes for use in VBA, the MSDN documentation you linked to is not the place to start.

Comment: I did notice that @AlanMoore, but couldn't seem to find the article for the VBScript implementation. Could you possibly provide a link if you know of the correct one?

Comment: Here's the VBScript regex information - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you @TimWilliams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular Expressions (aka "regex") are indeed scary-looking, but they're also a powerful tool, and VBA supports them, if you add a reference to the *Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5* library.

With it you can create a `RegExp` object, which gives you a `MatchCollection`, which is, well, a collection of `Match` objects.

Here's how to use them:

```
Sub Test()
    Const value As String = _
    "Available on 2 sides: Silkscreen,[full: color, covers entire face],Pad Print: One color,[heat transfer, may bleed]"

    Const pattern As String = _
    "(\[[^\]]+\]|[^,]+)"

    Dim regex As New RegExp
    regex.Global = True
    regex.pattern = pattern

    Dim matches As MatchCollection
    Set matches = regex.Execute(value)

    Dim m As Match
    For Each m In matches
        Debug.Print Trim(m.value) 'value will preserve any leading/trailing spaces
    Next

End Sub
```

Notice the `pattern` is pretty much that in [Laurel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36379700/1188513):

```
(\[[^\]]+\]|[^,]+)
```

By not specifying that you want to match a comma, you're not matching it (whether it's there or not) - hence, the above code outputs this:

```
Available on 2 sides: Silkscreen
[full: color, covers entire face]
Pad Print: One color
[heat transfer, may bleed]
```

You can easily iterate a `MatchCollection` to populate an array if you need one.

Comment: Does this regex handle a `[C,Y,M,K]` within `Available on 2 sides: Silkscreen,[full: color[C,M,Y,K], covers entire face],Pad Print: One color,[heat transfer, may bleed]`?

Comment: @ThunderFrame well, nested square brackets weren't part of the spec, so not really.

Comment: you mean the spec that says "This is data that suppliers send us, **we don't have control over what they enter or how they enter it**"? ;-)

Comment: @ThunderFrame you're mean ;-)

Comment: we should totally work on a parsing project. I'll find the edge cases, and you fix 'em. ;-p

Comment: Haha calm down fellas, can't we all just get along :) @Mat'sMug this will work perfectly for me and I found a way to avoid having to add the reference. Thank you so much, you've been such an amazing help with my problems and even with just showing me the ropes/explaining how things work on this site (and CR). You truly are a great senior member who cares and I just want to make sure that you know it has not gone unnoticed or unappreciated. I appreciate it more than you believe.

Comment: Haha I have no idea *what* that is, so I'm just going to keeping moving along before my head explodes with whatever is going on with that github project. Again, ease me into things or else (remember: fetal position, crying in the corner) ;)

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder I'd feel dirty to "advertise" my project in an unrelated comment thread, but my user profile has all the links (it's an add-in for the VBE)

Comment: By all means, you have my full permission to. After all you've helped me with it's the least I could do. I'll definitely have to check it out because knowing you it's probably something that would vastly benefit me.

Answer (score 3):

There are other ways, but this regex seems to be pretty fast:

`(\[[^\]]+\]|[^,]+),?`

Explanation:

`\[` and `\]` are escaped versions of `[` and`]`

Essentially, it's looking for a `\[`, gets all non brackets `[^\]]`, then the `\]`. Otherwise `|`, it will get all the non commas `[^,]`. The surrounding `()` makes it a capture group. `,?` means there may or may not be a comma.

Comment: How does this work? Sorry I'm very dumb when it comes to reading/understanding regex as of right now. That being said, I would need something that would be able to handle instances both with and without an ending comma (example: the last value in the cell doesn't have a trailing comma)

Comment: That gives me a slightly better idea of how it works (thank you!). Now, how could I use this to split the values in a cell up into an array?

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder [I don't know VBA, try here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300848/vba-regex-only-returns-first-match)

Comment: Nicely explained, well done - note that you can leave out the `,?` part, because you don't actually want that comma in your `Match`.

Comment: @Mat'sMug it's not in the capture group.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to take the bracketed commas and replace them with *Chr(184)*'s.  These little guys look a lot like commas.

Once the bracketed commas have been replaced, you can use normal *Split()*  Here is some code to do the replacement:

```
Sub parser()
    Dim s As String, s1 As String, s2 As String, pseudo As String
    Dim switch As Boolean, temp As String, CH As String

    pseudo = Chr(184)
    s1 = "["
    s2 = "]"
    s = [A1]
    switch = False
    temp = ""

    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If CH = s1 Or CH = s2 Then switch = Not switch
        If switch Then CH = Replace(CH, ",", pseudo)
        temp = temp & CH
    Next i

    Range("A2").Value = temp
    MsgBox s & vbCrLf & temp
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice approach, but would it be efficient when implementing this over thousands of rows, each row/cell possibly having over 100 characters? I'm just playing devil's advocate and trying to assume worst case scenario (because this has unfortunately happened before).

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder .............the reason I like the approach is I can pre-process thousands of records and then process them later..........I can even pre-process the stuff as part of the data import.

Comment: You could optimize this code to check for the presence of `[` and `]` *before* parsing all of the characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
Function Splitter(s)
    Dim p As Long, b As Long, l As String
    Dim c As Long, s2 As String, arr, n

    If InStr(s, "[") = 0 Then
        arr = Split(s, ",")
    Else
        c = 0
        For p = 1 To Len(s)
            l = Mid(s, p, 1)
            If l = "," And c = 0 Then
                Mid(s, p, 1) = vbNull
            Else
                If l = "[" Then c = c + 1
                If l = "]" Then c = c - 1
            End If
        Next p
        arr = Split(s, vbNull)
    End If
    Splitter = arr
End Function
```

Comment: Couldn't this be improved by doing a count of ]'s before looping? But, even then wouldn't it still be taxing on resources to run this on thousands of rows possibly having 100+ characters each?

Comment: If you have concerns about performance then it's pretty simple to test.  I ran a 10k loop over your sample string in about 0.4sec